# Boot directly into another kernel from running Linux without bootloader

Tags: linux, kernel, reboot

Is there a way to boot directly into another kernel on disk from a running Linux, without resetting the machine and going through the bootloader?

In theory, Linux should be able to load another kernel into RAM, load initrd as well, gracefully shutdown everything as in `shutdown` and then pass control to the new kernel.

Is there a practical way to do that?

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you are looking for [kexec](https://linux.die.net/man/8/kexec)

Example from the docs:

> For example, if the kernel image you want to reboot to is /boot/vmlinux, the contents of /proc/cmdline is root=/dev/hda1, and the path to the initrd is /boot/initrd, then you would use the following command to load the kernel:
>
> ```
> kexec -l /boot/vmlinux --append=root=/dev/hda1 --initrd=/boot/initrd
> ```
>
> After this kernel is loaded, it can be booted to at any time using the command:
>
> ```
> kexec -e
> ```

Comment: Do I need to call `shutdown` between `kexec -l` and `kexec -e`?

Comment: It has been a while since i played with kexec, but I do not remember having to issue `shutdown` as `kexec -e` should unload the old kernel and boot into the specified one.  The man page I linked has some good information and all the available options.

Comment: The idea was to at least unmount existing file systems etc. I read the man page, and googled, but couldn't find anything. Systemd can perform a controlled shutdown before kexec -e, but this is a non-systemd system. I'll guess I'll just give it a try ...

Comment: @dirkt, kexec predates systemd by years. The normal system shutdown procedure of whatever init system you are using is run, then in the last step, kexec is triggered instead of a reboot. The kernel performs its own shutdown, quiesces hardware, then executes the new kernel.

Comment: Can kexec be used to boot other operating systems (not just Linux)?

Comment: @JL2210: In theory, yes https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Google-Kexec-Windows-Linux

Answer (score 2):

concerning "as in shutdown":

it's only almost as in shutdown: all processes including `pid 1` are wiped, of course, since even the kernel is wiped out and reloaded. But some firmware stuff (EFI variables) can hang around, because kexec is not a full reboot.

If you are not (compiling and) testing one kernel after the other, kexec is of limited use. It is "experimental".

But it is cool to try out: it's "between" a reboot and a runlevel change (whatever that means in the days of systemd, or in fact, since always, in linux). After a few successful tries it crashed, so I let it be. (But nothing happened.)

I just read the latest comment:

> The idea was to at least unmount existing file systems etc.

But that is the same problem as with ctrl-alt-del, especially without systemd. Sorry for being sceptic, but the shutdown process with sysvinit really is a bit tricky already (with systemd also). A "controlled shutdown" together with kexec (or ctrl-alt-del) seems a bit paradoxal to me.

I always do some "etc." before I "pull the plug" on my system: close/save files, close firefox, check the tmpfs mount, unmount partitions...and then: `reboot`, `poweroff`, `halt`, `shutdown`, `init 6,` `init 0`, ctrl-alt-del or even ON/OFF button for five seconds...I don't want kexec as another source of potential problems.

---

added a few days later:

In fact systemd integrates kexec (`man systemctl`). I regret calling the idea "a bit paradoxal", but maintain my point: why not choose (or manually enter) that kernel command line a few seconds later at the bootloader's command line, after a normal reboot?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `efibootmgr` to check the number of the boot entry, BootNext (which usually contains 4 digits), and run the following command:

`# efibootmgr --bootnext BootNext`

From EFIBOOTMGR(8):

> • BootNext - the boot entry which is scheduled to be run on next boot. This supercedes BootOrder for one boot only, and is deleted by the boot manager after first use.  This  allows  you  to change the next boot behavior without changing BootOrder.

Comment: But UEFI boot entry and kernel command line are very 1-to-n. There is the boot loader in between with the boot menu. The idea is the same, on the UEFI layer. A _boot entry_ is connected with an "application" like "grub.EFI", or UEFI Shell.

Comment: In that way it's possible to boot directly into the other kernel without any menu prompt. You just have to `shutdown` (or `reboot`) after executing that command.

Comment: i think your solution is more useful than kexec for normal use. I did not recommend kexec in the first place, just picked up that "as in shutdown".

Comment: Only "problem" I see: normally you have one grub with a prompt. And you have to predefine your KCL. It really depends what you want.  I saw sytemd knows about these EFI options also.